# Asset pipeline url keeps changing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

It seems my Rails app in Heroku's Asset URL (application_user.js) keeps changing every time I refresh my browser.

Below is my Assets setting under production.rb:

```
  config.assets.enabled = true
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.action_controller.asset_host = "//#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}.s3.amazonaws.com"
  config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true
```

Also

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( '.woff', '.eot', '.svg', '.ttf', '*.css.scss', application_user.js, popcorn.js )
```

Below I have under `application.rb`:

```
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.digest = true
```

Comment: what do you mean 'keeps changing' ?

Comment: Can you share two examples of your asset's url? First before the page refresh and second after page refresh.

Comment: Whenever I refresh, I get different precompiled file (one) included so it can be user.js?12234 and then user.js?32244

Comment: sorry I mean something like `application_user-3c37b263ec073f77cd9917b56d955a37.js` then refresh to get `application_user-2df0b6d39dc60bb5ab4791ea6fbef8cb.js`

Comment: these URLs should only change on a deploy. Do you have a URL we can look at and see this for ourselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like an issue with [asset_fingerprinting](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark)

This is basically a way for Rails to mark your assets as unique / individual. I'm not exactly sure why it's done, but it's the reason why your files are having the hash appended to them each time

---

**Dynamic Paths**

If you're having problems with your hashed files, you should definitely look at using some dynamic path helpers in your SCSS or Javascript files:

```
   body, html { background: asset_url("layout/main/bg.png"); }
```

Comment: Javascript is included using `= javascript_include_tag "application_user"` does this make any difference?

Comment: Nope - it's a standard feature of rails! Is your problem that you can't load the assets you need (images etc)?

Comment: It's done to combat aggressive browser caching done by backwards browsers like IE - if IE decides to caches files by given names, no amount of cachebusting will help other than simply giving the files different names.

Comment: This only happens to one javascript file but not others

Comment: What's the problem though? Just loads the asset with the filename?

Comment: I've got asset_sync to upload to S3 but this doesn't seem to be working so I'm uploading manually any updated assets myself. It seems though whenever I change javascript file, it automatically generates 3-4 precompiled duplicate files

Comment: Hmmmm you shouldn't be uploading the file yourself - are you calling it through the manifest part of the file?

Comment: yes I am calling it through `= javascript_include_tag` and `application_user` includes other files using `require`